# Puzzling compiler optimisation result

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

If I try to run a loop like this:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 1e9; i++)
{
    1 + 1;
}
```

The compiler optimises it out completely and doesn't even run it.  But if I make the `int i` static, then it goes ahead and runs the loop, even when I went way higher iterations.  This is in Visual Studio 2013 with optimisation turned on in release mode.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `int` data type. In fact, when you declare variables in JavaScript you declare them with `var` and not with a data type. Variables in JavaScript don't have a type. Also, JavaScript is not compiled. It's interpreted.

Comment: Which language are you using? Which compiler? Which platform?

Comment: Also knowing the surrounding context is important for optimization.  Can you post the whole function?

Comment: Don't use a floating-point constant like 1e9 in integer code, that'll emit a lot of conversions and comparisons if you look at the generated assembly even if you don't use that. Use 1000000000 instead

Comment: "I like to make things static because my understanding is that they're not created and destroyed, but they remain until the program is closed." Bad programmer. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: That is the whole thing, it's in the main function.  This was using Visual Studio 2013, with optimisation turned on, as I said making the variable static made the compiler not optimise it.     @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, I didn't know 1e9 was a float number, I just do that because it looks cleaner.  I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that the body of the loop is a no-op. The only effect that the loop has is to change the value of `i`. When `i` has automatic storage, the compiler can prove that the value of `i` is never read after the loop. Therefore, the entire loop has no effect and can be discarded.

However, when `i` is `static` then its lifetime extends beyond the single call of the function. Therefore, the value of `i` is a side effect and the loop cannot be discarded.

You could argue that the compiler could dig deeper and prove that even a `static i` is never read, but that's a much more difficult proof to do.

Comment: I see your point, but in this case the int was declared static inside the main loop, not outside in in global space.  Thanks for the answer.  I guess it has something to do with what you said.

Comment: My answer assumes that it is declared static inside the function. If it's static outside the function then it would be a global variable (static in that case means it's only accessible within this one compilation unit, i.e. source file). The argument is the same in both cases.

Comment: Sorry I accepted and then unaccepted your answer, because I've been thinking about it, I don't think a variable declared static has scope outside the function it's been declared in.  It may not get destroyed upon leaving the function like a local automatic variable does, but the scope is still local, isn't it?

Comment: Good catch. The right word is lifetime. The variable has local scope in that it can only be accessed from inside the function, but its lifetime is the duration of the program, not the duration of the individual function call.

Comment: Yeah, so in that case, seeing as though it can't be modified by anything else, I'm still puzzled.  Hmm, there must be something I'm missing here.  Thanks for your help, Adam.

Comment: Assuming that `i` isn't accessed anywhere else in the function, the compiler could be smart enough to see that the whole piece of code has no effect. Anyway, if it wants to honor the variable `i`, it should convert the loop to `i= 1e9;`, a non trivial transformation.

Comment: The operative word is *prove*. The compiler must be extremely conservative in what it does to change your code. Emitting incorrect code is a cardinal sin for a compiler. Also, this is a relatively unimportant case for optimization because statics and globals should be avoided in performance critical code anyway.

Comment: If you want the code, here it is, paste it in, and see that when you take away the static it skips the loop altogether; 

void loop()

{
 static long long unsigned int i;
  
 for (i = 0; i < 1e12; i++)
 {
  1 + 1;
 }
}

int main()
{
 loop();
}

Comment: I'm hoping no one will mind if I bring this topic up again, because going through it, and six months later, I still haven't got it.  

Seeing as though the variable made static in the function is local, and cannot conceivably be changed in any way by anything outside the local space, I don't see why putting a static there throws away the optimisation.
The reason I wanted to put static there was because it ensures the lifetime of that variable for as long as the program runs, as it will be a very frequently called function.  As opposed to having int a, and int a being created every time.

Comment: What are you stuck on? If `i` is static, then its value will be read on the next call to the function, so the loop does have an effect and cannot be eliminated. Like I said above, if you're doing performance critical code then you should avoid statics. Your reasoning that you want to avoid i being created every time is not valid precisely because you limit the optimizer's options.

Comment: Adam, my thick head is finally starting to get around to it.  You're saying that because i is static, anytime it comes back to the function another time i will have the value that it left the function with, which in this case will be around 1 billion.

BUT, seeing as though the loop specifically assigns i to be zero again, the loop is a no-op any time the function is called.  

My stubborn self still holds that it should still be optimised out.  Is this the issue here?  That the compiler sees the static keyword and refuses to optimise, even though it doesn't make a difference in this case?

Comment: Pretty much. The compiler doesn't know how to optimize statics as well as non-statics because there are many ways the static's value can be read outside of this particular function call. I bet the compiler authors have much better optimizations to think about than this one.

Answer (score 1):

When i is not static, this entire piece of code does not affect the observable state of the program. As you've noticed, the compiler optimizes away the loop. This is called dead-code elimination.

Now when i is static, the VC++ compiler immediately gives up and not optimize the code (most non-trivial optimizations will not be used whether they are applicable or not). If two or more threads are calling the function concurrently, then most optimizations including dead-code elimination might cause observable side effects on the state of the program rendering them illegal.

Of course, in this case, we are not using any threads. But VC++ will not analyze the code (for good reasons) and so, to be safe, it just gives up.

If it did analyze the code and discovered that only one thread is calling the function, then it's actually capable of optimizing it by replacing the loop with an addition statement if i was static.